# Hide a UIBarButtonItem by sliding it to the left when search bar gets focus.

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar, uibarbuttonitem, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Let's suppose that's  my toolbar.

```
.---------------------.
|X |my searchbar  | Y |
.---------------------.
```

I'm using `UISearchDisplayController`'s `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar`to show a searchbar in the navigation bar. On each side i've a button.

```
[_searchController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:_locationButton];
[_searchController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:_favouriteButton];
```

Like Apple's Map app, I'd like the 2 buttons to disappear when the search bar gets the focus.

Using `UISearchBarDelegate` methods I came up with following :

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [_searchController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil];
    [_searchController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;

    [searchBar sizeToFit];

    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    searchBar.showsScopeBar = NO;
    [searchBar sizeToFit];

    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
    [_searchController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:_locationButton];
    [_searchController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:_favouriteButton];
    return YES;
}
```

It does almost what I want. Almost because the left button does not slide to the left but only disappear.

How can I make slide to the left like the "Start Route" on Maps.